# Editing a function made in VBA to count colours

Tags: vba, function, colors, count, macros

I've wrote some code to create a function that counts the colours of a cell.

```
Function CountCellsByColour(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range) As Long
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim cntRes As Long

    cntRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    cellPlusOne = cellCurrent + 1
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If (indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color) And (cellCurrent.EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
            cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    Next cellCurrent

    CountCellsByColour = cntRes
End Function
```

It works fine but I want to edit it to only count 1 if the coloured cells are touching. In the example below, when the function calculates the amount of colour for this range, it will pull 1 green and 3 reds (instead of 6). Is this possible

EDIT:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKmb2.png)

Comment: I would have thought that you'll need to use offset, so if r.color=true, then if r.offset(-1,0).color, r.offset(1,0).color etc to get the surrounding up to 8 cells, or perhaps handle the sheet in 9 cell blocks somehow?

Comment: The offset will work, but it's more involved than that. I'd create a 2D array to match the cell area you're looking at, then flag each array "cell" if its colored with a desigator/counter. That way if you have an area that is "L" shaped or more than two adjacent cells, you can more readily identify adjacency. But I'd probably look for an algorithm for this on the interwebz, because my guess is someone's already solved this problem programmatically (but maybe not in VBA for cells).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Function CountCellsByColour(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range) As Long
    Dim indRefColor As Long, previousMatchingRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cntRes As Long

    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    previousMatchingRow = -1 '<--| initialize previous matching cell row so as not to be "recognized" at the first iteration
    cntRes = 0
    For Each cell In rData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| loop through visible cells only
        If indRefColor = cell.Interior.Color Then
            If cell.Row > previousMatchingRow + 1 Then
                cntRes = cntRes + 1
                previousMatchingRow = cell.Row '<--| set previous matching cell row to the current matching cell
            Else
                previousMatchingRow = previousMatchingRow + 1 '<--| update previous matching cell row to the current "touching" cell
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    CountCellsByColour = cntRes
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, not the most elegant perhaps, produces a range, using the range argument supplied as the centre cell.  A further tip would be looking at -1 to 1 loops to reduce the code...

I checked using `? CHECK_ADJACENTS(range("i5")).Address` and got the result `$I$5,$J$4,$H$6`

```
Function CHECK_ADJACENTS(rngInput As Excel.Range) As Excel.Range

Dim lngCurrent As Long

lngCurrent = rngInput.Interior.ColorIndex

Set CHECK_ADJACENTS = rngInput

On Error Resume Next

    If rngInput.Offset(-1, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = lngCurrent Then
        Set CHECK_ADJACENTS = Union(CHECK_ADJACENTS, rngInput.Offset(-1, -1))
    End If

    If rngInput.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = lngCurrent Then
        Set CHECK_ADJACENTS = Union(CHECK_ADJACENTS, rngInput.Offset(-1, 0))
    End If

    If rngInput.Offset(-1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = lngCurrent Then
        Set CHECK_ADJACENTS = Union(CHECK_ADJACENTS, rngInput.Offset(-1, 1))
    End If

    If rngInput.Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = lngCurrent Then
        Set CHECK_ADJACENTS = Union(CHECK_ADJACENTS, rngInput.Offset(0, -1))
    End If

    If rngInput.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = lngCurrent Then
        Set CHECK_ADJACENTS = Union(CHECK_ADJACENTS, rngInput.Offset(0, 1))
    End If

    If rngInput.Offset(1, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = lngCurrent Then
        Set CHECK_ADJACENTS = Union(CHECK_ADJACENTS, rngInput.Offset(1, -1))
    End If

    If rngInput.Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = lngCurrent Then
        Set CHECK_ADJACENTS = Union(CHECK_ADJACENTS, rngInput.Offset(1, 0))
    End If

    If rngInput.Offset(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = lngCurrent Then
        Set CHECK_ADJACENTS = Union(CHECK_ADJACENTS, rngInput.Offset(1, 1))
    End If

    CHECK_ADJACENTS.Select

End Function
```